# Stabilizing lattices on the real plane

Tags: linear-algebra

For a homework problem I need to find all $A\in GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ that stabilizes some lattice $L$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I have deduced that $L$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module, and so left multiplication by $A$ is an isomorphism between modules. However, I am not quite sure how to approach from here on. Anyone with some ideas/hints, preferably starting from this step?

Comment: $\Lambda = M \mathbb{Z}^2$ for some $M \in GL_2(\mathbb{R})$. Therefore $A$ stabilizes $\mathbb{Z}^2$ iff $M AM^{-1}$ stabilizes  $\Lambda$. Also $A$ stabilizes $\mathbb{Z}^2$ iff  $A \mathbb{Z}^2 \subseteq \mathbb{Z}^2$ and both $(1,0), (0,1)$ are in $A \mathbb{Z}^2$. This means that $A$ must be in $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: @user1952009 I am sorry but could you please explain the second statement a bit more? I am getting: $L=M\mathbb{Z}^2$ so $A$ stabilizes $L\Leftrightarrow A$ stabilizes $M\mathbb{Z}^2\Leftrightarrow M^{-1}AM$ stabilizes $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Comment: Which results in the fact: $A$ stabilizes $L\Leftrightarrow A$ is similar to an invertible integer matrix.

Comment: Yes $A$ stabilizes $L$ iff $M^{-1} A M \in GL_2(\mathbb{Z}) = SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ (from the adjugate matrix formula : $ T \in R^{n \times n}$ has an inverse $\in R^{n \times n}$ iff $\det(T) \in R^\times$. When $R = \mathbb{Z}$ it means $\det(T) = \pm 1$)

Comment: But how does it imply that $A$ itself is an invertible integer matrix?

Comment: $A$ doesn't have to be an invertible integer matrix (let $(u,v)$ be a basis of $L$, and think to the transformation exchanging $u$ with $v$)

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks!